# Core Data: Where to put awakeFromFetch and awakeFromInsert?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, objective-c-category

I would like to override `awakeFromFetch` and `awakeFromInsert`.

As I leave the auto-generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses unchanged and put my custom code in categories, my **question** is:

Where do I put `awakeFromFetch` and `awakeFromInsert` in order that these methods get called correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your managed object subclass files are generated by Xcode, then you can also put the methods in a category of the managed object subclass, so that the code is not overwritten when you re-generate the class files in Xcode.

**MyEntity+Extensions.h**

```
#import "MyEntity.h"

@interface MyEntity (Extensions)
@end
```

**MyEntity+Extensions.m**

```
#import "MyEntity+Extensions.h"

@implementation MyEntity (Extensions)

- (void)awakeFromFetch
{

} 

- (void)awakeFromInsert
{

}
@end
```

Comment: Ok! I did not know that I can override methods in a customized category.

Comment: @AlexR: I have done it with `prepareForDeletion` and it worked.

Comment: @AlexR: See also [this link](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2002/Aug/msg00007.html): "When a category overrides an inherited method, the new version can, as usual, incorporate the inherited version through a message to super. ..." So there is no problem with overriding a inherited method of `NSManagedObject` in a category of `MyEntity`.

Comment: That means Core Data searches all existing categories for a `NSManagedObject` for a overwritten method and uses the overwritten method if it finds one? But how would Core Data prioritize the methods if there are more than one present?

Comment: @AlexR: No, you have a category for `MyEntity`, not for `NSManagedObject`. Therefore `awakeFromFetch` from that category is used if you send `awakeFromFetch` to a `MyEntity` object. There is no ambiguity.

Comment: I mean you could have for instance two categories named "initializer" and "fetch" in addition to your entity "Extension", import all three categories (`#import "MyEntity+xxxx`) and have a method `awakeFromFetch` in each of these categories.

Comment: @AlexR: If multiple categories implement the same method, then you cannot predict which one is called, so that is definitely not a good idea. - In my code I have just one category for each managed object subclass, which contains all custom methods and overridden methods from `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: Would it be possible to put the code in class extensions instead (somehow)?

Comment: @AlexR: Why would you want to do that? Class extensions must be implemented in the main implementation block for the corresponding class, i.e. in the Xcode generated file "MyEntity.m".

Comment: @AlexR: Did overriding the methods in a category work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to also consider [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator). It's a command-line tool which generates two classes for each of your managed objects and ensures your custom code is never overwritten when your model changes.

Comment: Mogenerator is the bomb.

Answer (score 2):

According to NSManagedObject class reference you should put it in a subclass - calling super implementation is necessary:

> Important:  Subclasses must invoke super’s implementation before performing their own initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement them in your subclasses. If the code is the same for all of your subclasses and you want to avoid copy-pasting them into each of them, I would suggest to write one subclass of `NSManagedObject` that implements them and then make your specific entity-classes subclasses of that class.

```
//MyManagedObject.h
@interface MyManagedObject : NSManagedObject
//...
@end

//MyManagedObject.m
@implementation
- (void)awakeFromFetch
{
    //...
} 
- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    //...
}
@end


//OneOfMyEntities.h
@interface OneOfMyEntities : MyManagedObject
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel making an extension is better option than subclass because in subclass you need to change the parent class again n again whenever you generate... i hope thats the better approach....

Comment: Why must the parent class be changed in the subclass if the name of the parent class stays the same?